# Handling duration in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, duration

I have a Rails 5 app where I'm building a workout planner. One of the fields is: `duration`.

I want to let users input a duration for a workout. Ideally, I would like to have it like this:

[image]

The input field should always default to HH:MM:SS.

My initial thought was to use HTML `input type="time"`, which behaves the correct way but cannot load with e.g. `@workout.time` as a placeholder; it will always look like --:--:--.

Is it a `timepicker` I'm looking for? It seems like timepickers behave like this 23:59:59, when it should be able to behave like this: 35:11:01.  What keywords should I look for?

Could this be solved with some simple javascript?

Comment: It sounds like the issue with your placeholder is that you're using placeholder. You want the value to be in the field when you reload so you should be setting the value instead of the placeholder to your saved duration I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Rails's ActionView form helpers, and the time_field element:

```
f.time_field :duration,
  value: f.object.duration&.strftime("%H:%M") || "%H:%M",
  min: 'hh:mm:ss',
  max: 'hh:mm:ss',
```

Adding min & max changes the default format from HH:MM to HH:MM:SS. See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html for more details!

Comment: This won't quite work as this generates a HTML5 `<input type="time">` - these are intended to select a time of day and are capped at 24 hours. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: If we assume 24 hours is an acceptable cap to have, then this actually works. The only thing that wont work with this is: I input a duration, it saves as workout.duration, when I load the page again, workout.duration does not show as the placeholder value, it is just --:-- again. Anyway to get around this? If possible, then that is the solution!

Comment: Try setting the value to `value: f.object. duration.strftime("%H:%M")`. This assumes that duration is a Date or Time column type. If its an integer you can cast it into a time with `Time.at(duration)` which will give the time from the Unix epoc.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the above?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm trying this one: = f.time_field :duration, class: 'form-control', value: f.object.Time.at(@workout.duration).strftime("%H:%M"), min: 'hh:mm:ss', max: 'hh:mm:ss', step: 2 but I'm getting the following error: undefined method `Time' for #<Workout:0x007ff946a38800>
Did you mean?  time?
               time=

Comment: @Andy you only need Time.at if your value is stored as an int (Unix epoc).